# Laws of logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do I solve this to show that the L.H.S = R.H.S

((p → q) ∨ (¬p → r)) → (q ∨ r) ≡ q ∨ r

I have to show this using the laws of logical equivalence.

I have made some attempt using implication law, associative law and commutative law, but I am not sure if these are the right laws and I am getting a bit confused. Help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just argue about the logical values. You know that if the assumption of implication is false, then the whole implication is true. You know that p is either true or false, so in the first bracket, (at least) one of the implications will be true, so also the disjunction will be true. Hence, the assumption of the 'large' implication is true, so the whole statement is true if and only if the conclusion is true — which is what you have on the R.H.S.

Answer (score 0):

> I have made some attempt using implication law, associative law and commutative law, but I am not sure if these are the right laws and I am getting a bit confused.

Yes, that is correct.  Begin by using implication equivalence on the antecedent's implications, then associate and commute that disjunction.

$$\begin{align}&((p\to q)\vee(\neg p\to r))\to (q\vee r)\\[2ex]&((\neg p\vee q)\vee(p\vee r))\to(q\vee r)\\[2ex]&((\neg p\vee p)\vee(q\vee r))\to(q\vee r)\end{align}$$

Now you should see the next move.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, but this is the part I am unsure on as far as writing out the next steps. so the first bracket (¬p∨p)  will be true, T, but then what do I write?

Comment: Indeed, next is $(\top\vee(q\vee r))\to(q\vee r)$ via Complementation, and of course this is followed with $\top\to(q\vee r)$ via Annihilation. Now use Implication Equivalence and continue….